# Getting route parameters in Lumen

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, lumen, lumen-5.4, lumen-routing

When trying to access Route parameters, using `$request->route('id')`, in latest version of Lumen, I get an error.

```
lumen.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: 
Call to a member function parameter() on array
```

It works fine in Laravel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lumen is so stripped down, that the Route resolves to a simple array, rather than a Route object.

This is a problem, since the `Request::route($key)` method assumes the Route will have a `parameter` method.

But if you call `Request::route(null)`, the complete Route array will be returned, looking something like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["uses"]=>
    string(40) "App\Http\Controllers\SomeController@index"
    ["middleware"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "auth"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "example"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(36) "32bd15fe-fec8-11e7-ac6b-e0accb7a6476"
  }
}
```

Where `[2]` always seems to contain the Route parameters.

I made a simple helper class to work with the Route parameters on Lumen. You can get, set and forget route parameters. This is works great if you need to manipulate them in your middleware.

Save in `app/Support/RouteParam.php`: https://gist.github.com/westphalen/c3cd187007e0448bcb7fca1de091e4df

And simply use it like this: `$id = RouteParam::get($request, 'id');`

Blame `illuminate/http/Request.php`:

```
/**
 * Get the route handling the request.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $param
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route|object|string
 */
public function route($param = null)
{
    $route = call_user_func($this->getRouteResolver());

    if (is_null($route) || is_null($param)) {
        return $route;
    }

    return $route->parameter($param); // can't call parameter on array.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Lumen just is not yet registers route information in the **global** middleware.

So, you'll just get empty string if you call `$request->route()`:

```php
class MyMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->route(); // empty string or null
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The decision is to define your middleware as a **route middleware** and manually set it to each needed route.
`bootstrap/app.php`:

```php
$app->middleware([
//    MyMiddleware::class, // do not use global middleware
]);

$app->routeMiddleware([
    MyMiddleware::class,
]);


// And then apply the middleware to every route using a group:
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    'middleware' => [MyMiddleware::class],
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php';
});
```

The final correct middleware:

```php
class MyMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // @see https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/119#issuecomment-298835011
        $route = $request->route();
        $routeParameters = is_array($route) ? $route[2] : $route->parameters();
     
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure where you are trying to access this, but if it's from the controller, the Lumen documentation explains that it's accessed by type-hinting it in the method: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/requests#accessing-the-request

From the documentation:

> You may still type-hint the Illuminate\Http\Request and access your route parameter id by defining your controller method like the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the specified user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  string  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```